# Need help with buttons alignment

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm having some trouble aligning vertically a set of jquery-ui buttons and controls. They represent a set of options, like a button bar :

http://jsfiddle.net/DeYb8/

The desired result is to have all controls centered vertically. You can see in the example the autocomplete (input and button) are not aligned with the other jquery ui buttons.

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: You want all of the buttons on one line? Or two rows of buttons?

Comment: just one row with all items nicely aligned verticalla (center)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind taking away the floating css, you could achieve this with `display:table-cell` styling. For example:

```
.icBoxToolbarInner > * {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/DeYb8/1/.

---

In regards to learning positioning, I found the [CSS Positioning](http://www.brainjar.com/css/positioning/) from BrainJar does a very good job explaining different aspect of positioning. If that's not enough, you could try the [Visual formatting model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html) from the official W3 recommendation. Other than that, just make sure you understand different types of displays and box models.

Comment: thanks, do you know a good place to learn div positioning, or a good place to find js gurus ?

Comment: for the former, see the updated answer. For the latter, here in SO :)

Comment: Thankk, I mean gurus who are ready to work for some month in a project

Comment: I suppose you could pay for the SO Career 2.0 service to find a candidate near you: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/candidate-search, or if you want to pay enough, I might relocate :p

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty fix would be to change part of your CSS to:

```
.icBoxToolbarInner *{
                     height:  20px;
                     display: inline-block;
                     vertical-align: middle;
                    }
```

Note the asterisk (*) above, and your HTML "button1" style to:

```
style="width:20px; height:12px"
```